# T-SQL syntax to show both negative values and NULL values as 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, zero, negative-number

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a query with this line of code:

```
ISNULL(b.[LEISURE],0) AS 'LEISURE'
```

The value of Leisure can also be negative, in which case I want the value to also show as 0.

How do I wrap both conditions in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your given block of code, use:

```
IIF(b.[LEISURE] IS NULL OR b.[LEISURE]<0, 0, b.[LEISURE])
```

or

```
IIF(b.[LEISURE]>=0, b.[LEISURE], 0)
```

Comment: Just love the simplicity of your solution!

Answer (score 4):

The `CASE` statement is the best way to do this.  You can do it with one comparison:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN b.leisure > 0 THEN b.leisure ELSE 0 END)
```

A `NULL` comparison does not evaluate to true when compared to `0`, so the explicit comparison the `NULL` is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

use CASE Expression..

```
Case when b.lesure<0 or b.lesure is null then 0 else b.lesure End
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.LEISURE IS NULL OR b.LEISURE <= 0 
       THEN 0
       ELSE b.[LEISURE] END AS 'LEISURE'
FROM dbo.TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`IIF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx):

```
SELECT IIF(LEISURE < 0, 0, COALESCE(LEISURE, 0))
```

If `LEISURE` is negative then the above `IIF` will evaluate to `0`, otherwise, if `LEISURE` is `NULL`, `COALESCE` returns `0` again, otherwise a positive value is returned.